# How does QLineEdit triger QAbstractItemDelegate::commitData

Tags: qt, delegates, qlineedit, qabstractitemmodel

I am developing a Qt application using `QTreeView` and `QAbstractItemModel`.
The model contains somewhat heterogenous data, which requires different controls for editing. I am implementing it by having a custom delegate, that queries `model.data(Qt::EditRole)` and the model would return the `QWidget` to be used as an editor.

I like how it works for `QLineEdit` - when I hit enter, `delegate::setModelData` is called automatically, so I do **not** have to connect `QLineEdit::editingFinished` to `QAbstractItemDelegate::setModelData()`, which is very convenient since the QLineEdit is returned from the model as `QWidget` to the delegate and it doesn't have to care what kind of widget it is.
With `QComboBox` it's a bit tricky - I want the comboBox to commit once the selection is made, so far I can only do it by `connect(myComboBox, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), myDelegate, commitData()));`
However, my delegate doesn't know the type of the editor widget and I do not want to edit the delegate's code for each new editor the model ends up passing it. I would really like to force combobox to do the same thing as QLineEdit does when the enter is clicked in the slot connected to its `activated()` signal.

So, what does the `QLineEdit` do to call delegate's `setModelData`?
Is there a generic way in Qt for the editor whatever it is to say "I'm done editing, take the data and pass it to the model"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QStyledItemDelegate` (and `QItemDelegate`) defines an event filter that calls `commitData` if you press tab or return.

See the following excerpt from the [Qt 4.8.6 source](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp?h=v4.8.6):

```
bool QStyledItemDelegate::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    QWidget *editor = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(object);
    if (!editor)
        return false;
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        switch (static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event)->key()) {
        case Qt::Key_Tab:
            emit commitData(editor);
            emit closeEditor(editor, QAbstractItemDelegate::EditNextItem);
            return true;
        case Qt::Key_Backtab:
            emit commitData(editor);
            emit closeEditor(editor, QAbstractItemDelegate::EditPreviousItem);
            return true;
        case Qt::Key_Enter:
        case Qt::Key_Return:
#ifndef QT_NO_TEXTEDIT
            if (qobject_cast<QTextEdit *>(editor) || qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit *>(editor))
                return false; // don't filter enter key events for QTextEdit
            // We want the editor to be able to process the key press
            // before committing the data (e.g. so it can do
            // validation/fixup of the input).
#endif // QT_NO_TEXTEDIT
#ifndef QT_NO_LINEEDIT
            if (QLineEdit *e = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor))
                if (!e->hasAcceptableInput())
                    return false;
#endif // QT_NO_LINEEDIT
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "_q_commitDataAndCloseEditor",
                                      Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QWidget*, editor));
            return false;
        case Qt::Key_Escape:
            // don't commit data
            emit closeEditor(editor, QAbstractItemDelegate::RevertModelCache);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        if (editor->parentWidget())
            editor->parentWidget()->setFocus();
        return true;
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut || (event->type() == QEvent::Hide && editor->isWindow())) {
        //the Hide event will take care of he editors that are in fact complete dialogs
        if (!editor->isActiveWindow() || (QApplication::focusWidget() != editor)) {
            QWidget *w = QApplication::focusWidget();
            while (w) { // don't worry about focus changes internally in the editor
                if (w == editor)
                    return false;
                w = w->parentWidget();
            }
#ifndef QT_NO_DRAGANDDROP
            // The window may lose focus during an drag operation.
            // i.e when dragging involves the taskbar on Windows.
            if (QDragManager::self() && QDragManager::self()->object != 0)
                return false;
#endif

            emit commitData(editor);
            emit closeEditor(editor, NoHint);
        }
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride) {
        if (static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) {
            event->accept();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Titusjan, for me the following did the trick:
        void CommittingCombo::_activated(const QString&)
        {
            static_cast<QWidget*>(parent())->setFocus();
            QEvent e(QEvent::FocusOut);
            QApplication::sendEvent(this, &e);
        }
Interesting, though, why did I have to send the lost focus event after shifting focus to parent - I hoped it would happen sort of automatically...